# ElasticSearch - Filter Buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

My elasticSearch **query** is like:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Infos.InstanceInfo.ID.keyword",
                "size": 1000
            },
            "aggs": {
                "tops": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 100,
                        "sort": {
                            "Infos.InstanceInfo.StartTime": "asc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, I have a **result** of this form:

```
aggregations
=========>group_by_id
==============>buckets
                {key:id1}
                ===============>docs
                {doc1.Status:"KO"}
                {doc2.Status:"KO"}
                
                {key:id2}
                ===============>docs
                {doc1.Status:"KO"}
                {doc2.Status:"OK"}
                
                {key:id3}
                ===============>docs
                {doc1.Status:"KO"}
                {doc2.Status:"OK"}
```

I'm trying to add a filter, so when "**OK**" the result must be like this:

```
aggregations
=========>group_by_id
==============>buckets
                {key:id2}
                ===============>docs
                {doc1.Status:"KO"}
                {doc2.Status:"OK"}
                
                {key:id3}
                ===============>docs
                {doc1.Status:"KO"}
                {doc2.Status:"OK"}
```

and for "**KO**" :

```
aggregations
=========>group_by_id
==============>buckets
                {key:id1}
                ===============>docs
                {doc1.Status:"KO"}
                {doc2.Status:"KO"}
```

Fields "**Startime**" & "**Status**" are at the same level "**Infos.InstanceInfo.**[...]"
Any idea?

> EDIT

Sample docs:

```
{
  "took" : 794,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_id" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 143846,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1000",
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "tops" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 6,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "vHFvoXYBVWrYChNi7hB7",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "1000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T00:43:56.011+01:00",
                        "status" : "KO"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609026236011
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "xHFvoXYBVWrYChNi7xAB",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "1000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T00:43:56.145+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609026236145
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "xXFvoXYBVWrYChNi7xAC",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "1000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T00:43:56.147+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609026236147
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "x3FvoXYBVWrYChNi7xAs",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "1000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T00:43:56.188+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609026236188
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "yHFvoXYBVWrYChNi7xAs",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "1000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T00:43:56.19+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609026236190
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "ynFvoXYBVWrYChNi7xBd",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "1000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T00:43:56.236+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609026236236
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "2000",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "tops" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "7HL_onYBVWrYChNij4Is",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "2000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T08:00:26.011+01:00",
                        "status" : "KO"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609052426011
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "9HL_onYBVWrYChNij4Kz",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "2000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T08:00:26.146+01:00",
                        "status" : "KO"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609052426146
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "3000",
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "tops" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 6,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "7nNRpHYBVWrYChNiiruh",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "3000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T14:09:36.015+01:00",
                        "status" : "KO"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609074576015
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "9nNRpHYBVWrYChNii7s5",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "3000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T14:09:36.166+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609074576166
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "93NRpHYBVWrYChNii7s5",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "3000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T14:09:36.166+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609074576166
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "-XNRpHYBVWrYChNii7ti",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "3000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T14:09:36.209+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609074576209
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "-nNRpHYBVWrYChNii7ts",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "3000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T14:09:36.219+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609074576219
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "azerty",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "_HNRpHYBVWrYChNii7ud",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Infos" : {
                      "InstanceInfo" : {
                        "ID" : "3000",
                        "StartTime" : "2020-12-27T14:09:36.269+01:00",
                        "status" : "OK"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1609074576269
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the status field is under `Infos.InstanceInfo` and it's of the `keyword` mapping, you can utilize the `filter` aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "status_KO_only": {
      "filter": {                                  <--
        "term": {
          "Infos.InstanceInfo.Status": "KO"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Infos.InstanceInfo.ID.keyword",
            "size": 1000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "tops": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 100,
                "sort": {
                  "Infos.InstanceInfo.StartTime": "asc"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this particular case you could've applied the same `term` query in the `query` part of the search request without having to use a `filter` aggregation.

---

If you want to get both `OK` and `KO` in the same request, you can copy/paste the whole `status_KO_only` aggregation, rename the 2nd one, and voila -- you now have both groups in one request. You can of course have as many differently named (top-level) filter aggs as you like.

Now, when you indeed need multiple filter aggs at once, there's a more elegant way that **does not require copy-pasting** -- enter the `filters` aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_statuses": {
      "filters": {                                     <--
        "filters": {
          "status_KO": {
            "term": {
              "Infos.InstanceInfo.Status": "KO"
            }
          },
          "status_OK": {
            "term": {
              "Infos.InstanceInfo.Status": "OK"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Infos.InstanceInfo.ID.keyword",
            "size": 1000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "tops": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 100,
                "sort": {
                  "Infos.InstanceInfo.StartTime": "asc"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any of the child sub-aggregations will automatically be the buckets of the explicitly declared term filters.

I personally find the copy/paste approach more readable, esp. when constructing such requests dynamically (based on UI dropdowns and such.)

Comment: I tried your first suggestion before, but it doesn't meet the expected result, because it will also return doc1 from id2 and doc1 from id3. For our logical business, it should return only id1's docs because there all KO. And the second query for searching for OK must return all the documents (even docs with KO) for the ids which have at least one document with OK (id2 and id3)..

Comment: Right. Can you update your question with a few sample docs?

Comment: Done. With 3 Ids : 1000, 2000 and 3000.

Comment: Hi Joe, do you think it's possible to achieve this result?

Comment: Just move the `filter` aggregation where you need it.

Comment: It will filter the docs inside the group_by aggregation and display all those with "KO" even id = 1000 & id = 3000 docs,I don't want to display these docs because these ids have other docs with "OK".. the KO filter for me should only display the ids having all docs KO

Comment: Why are there multiple same `InstanceInfo.IDs`? That's the crux here -- shouldn't they be unique?

Comment: no it's not unique, you can think of it as a session id in a way